# What should we do about this users spam-like answer behavior?

Tags: discussion, answers

What is the proper way of action about this new user, who spammed 14 identical answers in around an hour?

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/59097/celtic-sadness

The answer is rather poor in my opinion, they boil down to:

> This is complicated, I suffered from it, please see my solution in code [link] and my upcoming tutorial [sitelink]

Sometimes the answer is not even ontopic:

- [Isometric Tile maps in Cocos2d-x](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31945/isometric-tile-maps-in-cocos2d-x)
- [Best technique for drawing isometric tiles](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/47388/best-technique-for-drawing-isometric-tiles/92372#92372)
- didn't checked others

---

Here's rather disproportional users response. My comment was edited to add "and promoting your site":

[image]

---

Now he is deleting his answers I had pointed as off-topic and one with comments quoted above.

Comment: Looks like he just goes through [isometric] tag.

Comment: In general you safely vote to delete link-only answers. Especially if, in situations like this, they are borderline spammy (although you may want to flag the posts for moderator attention in that case as well).

Answer (score 5):

Flag the answers for moderator attention with a comment, or flag them as spam if they're really bad.

For these answers in particular:

I think if an answer happens to include a link to a tutorial you made, that's OK. However, if you're creating answers to direct users to a tutorial you made, that's promotion and not what this site is for.

I deleted some of the answers and edited others to remove the link to the personal site.

UPDATE

The user in question has now self removed all of their posts.